# Visual Studio 2010: Compilation designer.cs error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, updatepanel

I am using Visual Studio 2010 ,
if I use update panels , and do some changes in Markups , then in designer.cs 
System.UI is converted to System.Web.Webparts,
Which force me to changes all "designer.cs" files.

Has anyone else experienced this and are there any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a VS2010 bug in some releases. They do believe it's fixed now. Check this, will probably help:
[VS10-KB981167-x86.exe](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=27117&wa=wsignin1.0)

Comment: I have the same problem but cant install the fix because it does not apply on my machine. Any more info on this?

Comment: This particular link is for x86 machines, not sure if there's anything for x64 or others. http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB981167

Comment: I need the x64 fix :( I guess we'll have to wait for vs2011 to see this fixed :s